# How to get analytical formula of probability density function and cumulative distribution function for a distribution in R?

Tags: r, probability, probability-density

Is there anyway to print out the PDF/CDF formula for a distribution? E.g. for normal distribution I wish to run a command and see some formula printed `f(x) =  1/sqrt(.....)...`

I want to translate R's implementation of distributions like hyperbolic and EGB2 into Python and hope there is a way to fetch the formula from R elegantly rather than looking into the source code.

[image]

Comment: You could try to scrape it from the [infobox in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

Comment: @Henry  I want to check R's implementation for distributions like EGB2 or hyperbolic, guess wiki cannot help me looking to R's code.

Comment: No. Often the way computers calculate these PDFs won't resemble the traditional mathematical representations. You have to do to the source code if you really want to see what's happening. R is an analytical tool, not a theoretical one. If some distributions have different parameterizations, you usually can find the one R uses on the help page for a given function.